# Error when closing file stream whose existence depends on the same bool as the .close() statement in C++

Tags: c++, ofstream

I'm having trouble wording this question (as you might see from the title), but I'll try:

I'm opening a file stream (ofstream) if a bool variable is true, and then trying to close the file stream again if the same bool is true gives the error

```
'fout' was not declared in this scope"
```

Here is a minimal example:

```
using namespace std;
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    bool output = true;

    if (output) {
        ofstream fout("test.txt");
    }
    if (output) {
        fout.close();
    }
} // end main
```

What I'm trying to do is to open a file for storing some results from a program, only if the boolean "output" is true. I could just let it open the file every time (no if tests), but that gets very messy after a while, because the real file name depends on variables set in the program, and I don't want to overwrite any old files, so I'd rather do it this way.

EDIT: Today I learned what a "scope" is... Thanks guys!
Working code goes like this:

```
using namespace std;
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    bool output = true;
    ofstream fout;
    if (output) {
        fout.open("test.txt");
    }
    if (output) {
        fout.close();
    }
} // end main
```

Comment: You need to declare fout outside the if statement scope - then fout.open(...) in that scope

Comment: @Caribou I don’t like that solution, it makes the program state harder to reason about. I’d strictly separate code paths where the output stream exists and those where it doesn’t exist. In fact, the very existence of the `open` function is arguably an error – an existing stream should always be valid.

Comment: @KonradRudolph yes I agree - I was adressing the immediate minimal example above - I think that there are better ways to partition this kind of function as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you are defining "fout" in the "if-statement" and it is not defined out of that area(out of the if-statement)
you can instead do this :

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std ;

int main()
{
     ofstream fout ;
     bool output = true ;
     if(output)
     {
          fout.open("test.txt");
     }
     if(output)
     {
          fout.close(); 
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! I will be using your method, since I need the file stream later on, and don't want to open it (appending to the file) each time I need to write to it.

Answer (score 4):

You declare `fout` inside the scope of the if block, the else block has separate scope with it's own automatic variable of which `fout` is not one.

Yet you don't actually need to worry about it here, the `ofstream` will close itself when it falls out of scope because it abides by RAII.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization

I fact letting it close it's self is preferable to doing yourself.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream

(Note the comment next to the destructor).

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    bool output = true;

    if (output) {
        ofstream fout("test.txt");
                    //do with fout, let it close itself
    }
} // end main
```

The above code is fine.

Comment: Thanks! Does this work if I declare fout inside a void() before main() as well? Meaning, does it close itself when the void() exits?

Comment: The Only thing with this is that fout is no longer availiable outside that initial if statement, and ALL processing to do with the serialisation to that stream needs to occur in that scope.

Answer (score 0):

Food for Thought :)

The simple solution to the minimal example is to either declare the `ofstream` in a scope where it exists for the duration of the time you need to use it. Then you just have your conditional statements where you want to actually use the stream:

```
{
    bool output = someArgOrTestResult;
    ofstream myOutStream;

    if( output ) mOutStream << "Whatever";

}
```

However the repeated conditional statements can get (a) ugly, and (b) hard to maintain if you decide at sometime to change behaviour. So it might be beneficial to look at what you are doing and create an `MyOutput` class.

```
class MyOutput
{
private:
    std::string filename;
    bool output;
    ofstream fout;

public:
    MyOutput( const std::string& fn , bool out ) : filename(fn) , output(out) 
    {
         if( output )
             fout.open(filename); //Check syntax might need .c_str()       
    }

    ~MyOutput()
    {
         if( output )
             fout.close();
    }

    //There are many ways to expose the output function but simplest
    void write( const std::string& data )
    {
         if( output )
         {
             output << data;
         }
    }

};
```

**NOTE** - there is a lot missing in terms of error checking that you would need to put in - for example what happens if filename can't be opened.

Then in main you can have something like this:

```
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    bool output = true;
    MyOutput fout("test.txt",output);

    std::string myLocalData = "Some stuff....";
    fout.write(myLocalData);


} // end main
```

The advantage now is that you can just have the statement to write data without the surrounding test. There are a million variations on this, and it might be that the stuff you want to write can even be accessed if `output` is not set, but if that's the case then maybe the processing needs to be in `MyOutput` as well although it would need a rename and different methods...

Comment: I have never used classes before, so this goes a bit over my head. But thanks anyway, I'll look into it when I have passed my exams in Computational Physics! The code is starting to get a bit ugly with the if-tests, but it does the job for now.

Comment: @FilipSund and thats the point to be honest - if it does what and it isn't your career you don't need to worry :)